# login fail for windows authentication on a new server

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, windows-authentication

I have a backup of my SQL database and restored on another computer. Now when I try to login to it programmatically using C# I get error:

> Login failed for user 'new computer name'".

I am using windows authentication and my connection string looks like this:

```
Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog="office_ session";Integrated Security=True
```

when I try Visual studio -> server explorer -> connect to a database wizard
everything works fine.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you running your app as a service?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a website, is it running in Visual Studio? If so is it running under Cassini webserver or IIS Express? If so, check whether Windows authentication is on (press F4 when the webapplication project is selected).

Comment: No, Just a windows application.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database was set up to use local users for authentication on the other computer. Integrated Security means that your Windows logon will be used to authenticate with the database.

Try granting database access to your user in SQL Server Management Studio. If you are unable to do this, change the connection string to use a different login.

Comment: Actually the new computer has no management studio. But as I mentioned visual studio connection wizard produces the same string and connects perfectly.

Comment: You may be able to connect to the database using Visual Studio connection wizard, however your user may not have rights to perform database operations such as SELECT on a table, run a stored procedure, etc. I suspect this is the case here.

Comment: Right. Error arises on Fill method

Comment: What SQL statement does the Fill method call? If it's an SP, you'll need to grant execute access to that SP for your user. If it's an INSERT or UPDATE, you'll need to grant table-level permissions.

Comment: you mean I do this:

SELECT SUSER_ID('new_user') -- (**not** SUSER_SID)

If @@ROWCOUNT = 0

CREATE LOGIN [new_user] FROM WINDOWS

If not @@ROWCOUNT = 0

USE [My_DB]
GO
SELECT USER_ID('new_user')

If @@ROWCOUNT = 0

USE [My_DB]
GO
CREATE USER [new_user] FROM LOGIN [new_user]

Comment: no, that would create the user itself. you need to use a GRANT statement to allow the user to perform the operation